# añadir drag and drop a phonegap

Tags: html5, cordova, phonegap, drag-and-drop

Hace relativamente poco que me puse en el mundillo de `Phonegap` entre las app de prueba he creado una simple que crea un listado de tareas, la cuestión es que pensé en añadir la opción de poder modificar el orden de este listado al arrastrar el elemento.

Para ello pensé en utilizar la API de `HTML5` de drag & drop y que he utilizado en diversas ocasiones en alguna web, pero he visto que esto no funciona en el móvil. He investigado un poco con san google por si había alguna pega en utilizar esto y he encontrado algunos sitios donde indican que esto en un móvil android no funciona, no se si esto es así (ya que dichos articulos tienen fecha de varios años) o es que tengo que utilizar algo específico de `Phonegap`.

También probé con las opciones de drag & drop de `JQuery` que también he llegado a utilizar en webs y tampoco funciona. Al final logré hacerlo funcionar con una librería llamada `Dragula` y funciona tal como quiero, pero intento siempre usar menos librerías, ya que si no parece que estés dependiendo de un montón de sitios ajenos.

Alguién ha logrado que le funcioné la API de `HTML5`de drag & drop para una app creada con `Phonegap` en un móvil android?

Comment: Me encontré con un problema similar: no me funcionaba el drag & drop de HTML5 por ser un dispositivo táctil y no encontraba ningún modo. Como estaba usando jQuery, usé una extensión/plugin que se encargaba de eso. No sé si eso es una opción viable en tu caso.

Comment: A que extensión te refieres? si que me serviría ya que también intenté realizarlo con jquery ui con sus funciones drag & drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me encontré con un problema similar: estaba haciendo un juego con Phonegap/Cordova en el que usuarios agarraban y soltaban piezas en un puzzle, y no me funcionaba correctamente el drag & drop de HTML5 por ser un dispositivo táctil. Como estaba usando jQuery, probé con jQuery UI y su drag & drop, pero tampoco funcionaba.

Finalmente encontré una extensión/plugin para jQuery UI que era precisamente para adaptar el drag & drop a pantallas táctiles: [jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/). Es muy fácil de usar, simplemente lo incluyes en tu proyecto y ya está, no necesitas hacer nada más.

Como se explica en el sitio web del proyecto, el problema es que jQuery UI sólo controla los eventos del ratón (`mouseove`, `mousemove`, `mouseout`, etc.) pero no los eventos táctiles (*touch events*: `touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchend`). jQuery UI Touch Punch usa eventos simulados para mapear los eventos táctiles a eventos de ratón.

Esa extensión me funcionó de maravilla. Espero que te sirva a ti también.

Comment: Gracias, lo he probado y esta muy bien, ya que sólo tienes que añadir el link a dicho plugin, lo codificación con el jqueryUI se queda igual, no hay que añadir ninguna línea extra.